# What are spatial Transformations?

Tags: geometry, transformation, transformational-geometry

What are spatial Transformations? Are Affine transformations also part of spatial transformations?

Comment: Surely a google search would have solved this?

Comment: I tried googling, but I couldn't find any site which actually explained what Spatial transformations are. For affine transformations, it was pretty clear here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are. Spatial transformations as used in signal/image processing you mean?

Yes affine transformations are a special case of that.
 Top result [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spatial%20transformation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: I see, is there any definition available? This is what I can guess. It's just any transformation in 3D space.

Comment: Did you read the pdf that is the top result on google? There are definitions of both spatial and affine transformations. Is this in the context of image processing? A transformation can happen in any number of dimensions.

Comment: Haha.. The definition was quite difficult to understand, will look again, thanks!

Comment: Ok, cool well, I hope this helped. Yes the definitions are fairly general, that's a good thing, even though it makes it hard to get into at first :). There are some worked examples later on.